# Ajax Calls and Callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, settimeout

I have this JavaScript function.

```
function create_categories(callback) {
   cart_cats = [];
   E.Cart.calculateTotal(function(order) {
     cart_total = order.total;
     cart_items = order.cart.items;
     // loop through the items to get their categories.
     for(var i=0; i<cart_items.length; i++) {
        get_product_category(cart_items[i].product.id);
     }
   });

   setTimeout(callback, 3000);
}
```

the `get_product_category` function makes an ajax call, to get the category for a `cart_item` and then pushes it into the `cart_cats` array, which is a globally declared, and I need to use it in my `callback`

Now I don't want to use `setTimeout` here because I can never be sure of the maximum time that `create_categories` function can take to execute after which I call the `callback`, because the `cart_items` can contain many items.

I want to call the callback when the for loop finishes execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function create_categories(callback) {
   cart_cats = [];
   E.Cart.calculateTotal(function(order) {
     cart_total = order.total;
     cart_items = order.cart.items;
     completed = 0;
     for(var i=0; i<cart_items.length; i++) {
        get_product_category(cart_items[i].product.id);
        completed++;
     }
     if(completed == cart_items.length){
        callback;
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: `callback;` should be `callback();`.

Comment: Okay.. it works!.. but can you help me understand it.. My understanding was that since `get_product_category` is making ajax call the control will move on ahead (out of the for loop) and execute the if statement. Isn't that so? When does it move ahead and when does it wait for statements to finish?

Comment: @Mubashar: if this worked, would you consider accepting it? It is not mandatory here, but it is useful for both answerers and future readers.